# Cordova and PhoneGap have different config.xml examples

Tags: cordova

When I generate a new PhoneGap 2.3 app, the `config.xml` file is for Cordorva, and does not match *any* example listed by PhoneGap. This includes the example app on Github (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml). What do I need to do to get things going?

Comment: What is not running? The easiest way is to generate a sample-project and use that as example for the own application.

Comment: It's not that something isn't running, it's that documentation for PhoneGap uses one configuration file that is *entirely* different than what PhoneGap generates for a new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different config.xml files. One is located in "project_path/res/xml/config.xml" that is used by the native part of Cordova. The second one is used by PhoneGap Build service -  https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: In the latest phonegap 3.0.x version there is only one config file and this one is nearly identical between cordova and phonegap-build. You should tell for which phonegap version you answer may be valid.

Comment: The question was about PhoneGap 2.3

Comment: I think the distinction exist even in 3.0 for locally built projects (see http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/)

Comment: @Hexodus, can you reply to some of my questions about phonegap/cordova?

Comment: @eeadev I would if I could but I affraid that I really can't. I switched one year ago to [adobe online build system][1] because this so much easier. So I'm out from this home building stuff but hey, maybe this is the way to go for you too...


  [1]: https://build.phonegap.com/